# Comparing two variables sting array to see if any value matches - javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, user-input

Hi I am trying to compare two arrays to each other and then hide a list element if any of the values match.

One array is tags that are attached to a list item and the other is user input.

I am having trouble as I seem to be able to cross reference one user input work and can't get multiple words against multiple tags.

The amount of user input words might change and the amount of tags might change. I have tried `inArray` but have had no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. See code below:

```
function query_searchvar() {
   var searchquery=document.navsform.query.value.toLowerCase();
   if (searchquery == '') {
      alert("No Text Entered");
   }
   var snospace = searchquery.replace(/\s+/g, ',');
   event.preventDefault();
   var snospacearray = snospace.split(',');

   $('li').each(function() {
      var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
      //alert(searchtags);
      var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
      //alert(searcharray);
      var searchtrue=-1;

      for(var i = 0, len = searcharray.length; i < len; i++){
          if(searcharray[i] == searchquery){
              searchtrue = 0;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (searchtrue == 0) {
         $(this).show("normal");
      }
      else {
         $(this).hide("normal");
      }
   });
}
```

Okay so I've tried to implement the code below but have had no luck. It doesn't seem to check through both arrays.

```
function query_searchvar()
{
var searchquery=document.navsform.query.value.toLowerCase();
if(searchquery == '')
{alert("No Text Entered");
}
var snospace = searchquery.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
event.preventDefault();
var snospacearray = snospace.split(' ');
alert(snospacearray[1]);

$('li').each(function() {
  var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
  alert(searchtags);
  var searcharray = searchtags.split(' ');
    alert(searcharray[0]);

jQuery.each(snospacearray, function(key1,val1){
    jQuery.each(searcharray,function(key2,val2){
        if(val1 !== val2) {$(this).hide('slow');}
    });
});
});
}
```

Working code:

```
function query_searchvar()
{
var searchquery=document.navsform.query.value.toLowerCase();
if(searchquery == '')
{alert("No Text Entered");
}
var queryarray = searchquery.split(/,|\s+/);

event.preventDefault();


$('li').each(function() {
  var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
  //alert(searchtags);
  var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
//alert(searcharray);
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++)
    if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], queryarray)>-1) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

if (found == true )
  {

 $(this).show("normal");
  }
else {
$(this).hide("normal");
}
});
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are comparing an array to a String, not two arrays.

Comment: Maybe try adding some console logs in for search tags, search array, snospace array? And cna you confirm all the values are correct? Try replacing if(val1 !== val2) with != see if that helps?

Comment: I have a question: Can I have nested .each functions. So i have $('li').each(function and inside I have the other .each functions. When I use this.hide its not picking up the li item. Also I when I alert val1 and val2 I am not getting the elements in the array. Do you think I have my arrays set up wrong. Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in firefox, the input box won't save into the array. Would anyone know if this Is this a firefox issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var snospace = searchquery.replace(/\s+/g, ',');
var snospacearray = snospace.split(',');
```

Note that you can split on regular expressions, so to the above would equal:

```
var queryarray = searchquery.split(/,|\s+/);
```

---

To find whether there is an item contained in both arrays, use the following code:

```
var found = searcharray.some(function(tag) {
    return queryarray.indexOf(tag) > -1;
});
```

Although this will only work for ES5-compliant browsers :-) To support the others, use

```
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++)
    if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], queryarray)>-1) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
```

In plain js, without [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
var found = false;
outerloop: for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++)
    for (var j=0; j<queryarray.length; j++)
        if (searcharray[i] == queryarray[j]) {
            found = true;
            break outerloop;
        }
```

A little faster algorithm (only needed for really large arrays) would be to sort both arrays before running through them linear.

Comment: The only thing is the array lengths can vary so one might be longer then the other.

Comment: Of course they can. The code will search through all items until it finds one.

Comment: Thanks got it working, thank you so much.  I'm still unsure of how this works. If I have searcharray.length is that referring to the length of this array only? how does it look though the other items in the other array if that one is longer?

Comment: Yes, the [length property of Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is referring to the length of the array instance. And the loops just run through all indizes until length, so that every item is traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's psuedo code that should solve your problem.

```
get both arrays
for each item in array 1
    for each element in array 2
        check if its equal to current element in array 1
           if its equal to then hide what you want
```

An example of this coude wise would be

```
jQuery.each(array1, function(key1,val1){
    jQuery.each(array2,function(key2,val2){
        if(val1 == val2) {$(your element to hide).hide();}
    });
});
```

If there's anything you don't understand please ask :)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response. I will give that a go and see if I can get it working. Really appreciate it, very helpful.

Comment: okay, will do. I'll update with new code when its implemented.

Comment: Hi, I have had no luck getting this to work. I am thinking I don't have the arrays set up properly or something.

Comment: query_searchvar()
{
var searchquery=document.navsform.query.value.toLowerCase();
if(searchquery == '')
{alert("No Text Entered");
}
var snospace = searchquery.replace(/\s+/g, ',');
event.preventDefault();
var snospacearray = snospace.split(',');
//alert(snospacearray[1]);

$('li').each(function() {
  var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
  //alert(searchtags);
  var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
  
jQuery.each(snospacearray, function(key1,val1){
    jQuery.each(searcharray,function(key2,val2){
        if(val1 !== val2) {$(this).hide('slow');}
    });
});
});
}

Comment: Canyou edit your question to include this code as it is unreable here